# Open Layers map not showing pointers drupal7

Tags: 7, javascript

I have created a content type in drupal 7 and added a reference to a taxonomy term.The taxonomy term has geofield data i.e Longitude and Latitude.
The challenge is when I create a view and use an Openlayers data overlay following what is provided in the open layers documentation I do not have a pointer on my map. Could there be anything I am not doing right here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a slight tiff at the moment betwen Views 7x-3.5 and Openlayers 7x-2.0beta. I rolled back to 7x-3.3 and my markers were back. I am filing a bug report for views. Thank you people for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used a non-default PIN image, the URL it then used was incorrect, it included '?q', so the pin image didnt display. This was using openlayers-7.x-2.0-beta1, and when I applied the openlayers-fix-marker-lang-path-1404912-3.patch (http://drupal.org/node/1404912) it was fixed and worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a view with a page or block display and set it to "Openlayers map" mode.

The you add another display of type "Openlayers Overlay Data" and here add a relation based on term field. In this display add fields about latitude and longitude and edit settings of the display.

Finally you have to create map, or edit an existing map, and you have to add the layer "Openlayers Overlay Data" you have just create.
Remember to set the right openlayers map on the display "openlayers map" in the view.

Comment: I have already done all of the above and even gotten the map to display on a page.The issue is that the map is showing fine.The pointers are not. Thanks

Comment: Are you showing the right map? Did you add the right layer to the map? Are you passing the right field in the display "Openlayers Overlay data"? Try to get the preview of this display and check if you see lat and long

Comment: I tend to believe the issue is with the referencing of another field. When the fields are from the node directly I get my pointers. Looks like thats the approach I'll have to take, Thanks @sergiod